# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindParam()

Tags: php, pdo

What is wrong with this line? It is throwing up the above error.

```
$con->bindParam(':keyword',$keyword,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

\
$con is the database connection and works on other pages. :keyword is the item searched for and $keyword the variable attached to the user's input.

Comment: [`bindParam()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) is a member of PDOStatement, not PDO(connection).

Comment: Thank you Daedalus. All the html stuff is now showing but without the php table displaying the results. Just need to find out why now.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from this example ([PDOStatement::bindParam](http://%20https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#99698)), you should first instance $sth object from your $con with the *prepare* method, then use it to bind params in the query like so:

```
$sth = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `firstname` LIKE :keyword');
$keyword = "%".$keyword."%";
$sth->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

As you say it works on other pages, I guess you just did forget a step.

Comment: Thank you Luca. Have changed the code to something similar ($stmt in place of $sth) and seem to be making progress although the script still isn't working.